# Infinite looping row of images

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I create a scrolling row that scrolls automatically at a fixed speed that loops around the content of a list of images?

I have a lazy row of images as defined below, but haven't found a good way to loop it (like a carousel).

```
var images: List<String> = listOf()
repeat(8) {
    images = images.plus("https://place-puppy.com/300x300")
}
val state = rememberLazyListState()
LazyRow(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    state = state
) {
    items(count = images.size) { i ->
        val image = images.get(i)
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(40.dp)
                .aspectRatio(1f)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(image),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, create an infinite auto-scrolling effect that will be running as long as the composable is active & displayed:

```
LazyRow() {
  ....
}
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    autoScroll(lazyListState)
}
private tailrec suspend fun autoScroll(lazyListState: LazyListState) {
    lazyListState.scroll(MutatePriority.PreventUserInput) {
        scrollBy(SCROLL_DX)
    }
    delay(DELAY_BETWEEN_SCROLL_MS)

    autoScroll(lazyListState)
}

private const val DELAY_BETWEEN_SCROLL_MS = 8L
private const val SCROLL_DX = 1f
```

Secondly, update positions of items in the list accordingly:

```
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyRow(
        state = lazyListState,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        items(images) {
            ...

            if (it == itemsListState.last()) {
                val currentList = images

                val secondPart = currentList.subList(0, lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex)
                val firstPart = currentList.subList(lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex, currentList.size)

                rememberCoroutineScope().launch {
                    lazyListState.scrollToItem(0, maxOf(0, lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset - SCROLL_DX.toInt()))
                }

                images = firstPart + secondPart
            }
        }
    }
```

That should give you the looping behavior.

Credits: https://proandroiddev.com/infinite-auto-scrolling-lists-with-recyclerview-lazylists-in-compose-1c3b44448c8